# Leave checkboxes checked when using the searchview function in the listview

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, searchview

I am new at programming and have been looking for a solution to my problem for days.(on Android Studio)

I created a listview with searchview, then I added the checkboxes.
The problem with the checkboxes is that they don't keep their position when you search for something.
For example:
If I have 5 words.

Item1
Cheese

Item2
Sausage

Item3
Bread

Item4
Ketchup

Item5
Lemon

and I check the first word (Item 1 cheese) and search for Lemon (Item 5) , Lemon is checked because it is then on the first position (on item 1).

picture example:

1. check the 1st position:

[checked position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frygr.jpg)

[search for a letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIvJo.jpg)

2. check a word and search for it

[check a word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNgyj.jpg)

[search for the letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk99w.jpg)

How can I set that not the positions but the names are checked?
I was thinking if you can do this with an array, when you check something it goes into the array and stays there as checked and when you uncheck it goes back into the other array. Unfortunately I don't know exactly how to do that. (I have already tried around)

Maybe you can also assign ID's to the positions but I don't know if there is another solution than to give each position an ID because it should be more than 200 positions later.

For the checkbox i use ( android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" ) in Listview
Some Imports are for other functions in the code. (toolbar,drawer,etc.)

Here are my codes:

StorageActivity.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.text.Transliterator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StorageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

ListView listView;
String[] spices = {"Ajowan","Anis","Annatto","Bergkümmel","Betram","Brotklee","Eberraute","Essigbaum","Harissa","Herbes","Ingwer","Knoblauch","Koriander","Mandel"};
SearchView searchView;
ArrayList<String> selected = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_storage);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.lvspices);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,spices);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_spices);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            StorageActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            StorageActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

activity_storage.xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
tools:context=".StorageActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/home_screen"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/ToolBarTheme"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/notiButton"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.473"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.454" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/notiButton"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_notifications"
                    android:contentDescription="NULL"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/notification_circle"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/notiButton"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/notiButton">


                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/notification_number"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_spices"
        app:queryHint="Search Spice"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ebecf0">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvspices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:background="@color/beige"
        tools:listitem="@layout/support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item"/>


</LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for your help